# how to set textfield and pickerView parallel?

Tags: ios, constraints

I am making an iOS app and I want to set `UITextField` and `UIPickerView` parallel in my `UIViewController` but I cant set. Please help me. here I am attaching screenshots of `UIViewController` and a result on simulator.
I tried to add constraints but still facing same problem.
Help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Simulator image]
[image: ViewController image]

Comment: Are there any items in your pickerView? And try temporarily to set your pickerView's background color to a different colour, so you can see where the actual pickerView is on the screen.

Comment: yeah let me try. Actually i am new to ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Give constraint to picket view 
Center.X & center.Y to view
Trailing to view
equal height & width to view

Give constraint to textfield
leading to view
trailing to picker view
center.Y to picker view
```

See the below image

[image]